# Azure Storage Data Movement In lower bandwidth

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, blobstorage

Uploading multiple files (100Mb, 200Mb, 300Mb) at a bandwidth of 50kbps. Error was thrown after 30minutes with all the files failed.

**Code:**

```
            TransferManager.Configurations.BlockSize = 4 * 1024 * 1024; //4MB

            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri(destSasUrl));

            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

            SingleTransferContext context = new SingleTransferContext();

            context.SetAttributesCallbackAsync = async (src, dest) =>
            {
                CloudBlob destBlob = dest as CloudBlob;
                destBlob.Properties.ContentType = MimeMapping.MimeUtility.GetMimeMapping(Path.GetFileName(sourcePath));

            };

            TransferManager.Configurations.ParallelOperations = 2;

            // Start the upload
            Task task = TransferManager.UploadAsync(sourcePath, blockBlob, null, context);
            await task;
```

**Exception:**

```
at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement.TransferScheduler.ExecuteJobInternalAsync(TransferJob job, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\repo\DM\azure-storage-net-data-movement\lib\TransferScheduler.cs:line 239
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement.SingleObjectTransfer.ExecuteAsync(TransferScheduler scheduler, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\repo\DM\azure-storage-net-data-movement\lib\TransferJobs\SingleObjectTransfer.cs:line 223
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement.TransferManager.DoTransfer(Transfer transfer, TransferContext transferContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\repo\DM\azure-storage-net-data-movement\lib\TransferManager.cs:line 1777
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement.TransferScheduler.ExecuteJobInternalAsync(TransferJob job, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\repo\DM\azure-storage-net-data-movement\lib\TransferScheduler.cs:line 239
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement.SingleObjectTransfer.ExecuteAsync(TransferScheduler scheduler, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\repo\DM\azure-storage-net-data-movement\lib\TransferJobs\SingleObjectTransfer.cs:line 223
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement.TransferManager.DoTransfer(Transfer transfer, TransferContext transferContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\repo\DM\azure-storage-net-data-movement\lib\TransferManager.cs:line 1777
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement.TransferScheduler.ExecuteJobInternalAsync(TransferJob job, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\repo\DM\azure-storage-net-data-movement\lib\TransferScheduler.cs:line 239
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement.SingleObjectTransfer.ExecuteAsync(TransferScheduler scheduler, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\repo\DM\azure-storage-net-data-movement\lib\TransferJobs\SingleObjectTransfer.cs:line 223
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement.TransferManager.DoTransfer(Transfer transfer, TransferContext transferContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\repo\DM\azure-storage-net-data-movement\lib\TransferManager.cs:line 1777
```

**Error:** "The transfer failed".

**Storage Blob:** 12.4.4

In faster bandwidth it works well.

Comment: You can try to store the `checkpoint` when error occurs, then try to upload again from the checkpoint. Take a look at [this sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement/blob/master/samples/DataMovementSamples/DataMovementSamples/Samples.cs#L151).

Comment: @IvanYang How do you want me to write it after an exception is thrown? can you post it as an answer??

Comment: yes, write it after the exception. I'll post it later.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a checkpoint if the error occurs. Then upload again from the checkpoint.

For example:

```
        TransferCheckpoint checkpoint = null;
        SingleTransferContext context = new SingleTransferContext();

        try
        {
            // Upload a local blob
            var task = TransferManager.UploadAsync(
                sourcePath, destBlob, null, context, CancellationToken.None);
            task.Wait();
        }
        catch
        {
            // Store the transfer checkpoint
            checkpoint = context.LastCheckpoint;

            // Create a new TransferContext with the store checkpoint
            SingleTransferContext resumeContext = new SingleTransferContext(checkpoint);
            // Upload from the checkpoint
            var task = TransferManager.UploadAsync(
                sourcePath, destBlob, null, resumeContext, CancellationToken.None);
            task.Wait();
        }
```

You can also modify the code in a loop if you think the error does not occur only once.

And you know that the root cause is due to the low bandwdith, the best solution should improve it. The team is also considering [add bandwdith as a parameter](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement/issues/205).

Comment: It seems i'm getting exception inside the exception part.